# 1999 Giant Lafree Sport ebike charger

Tags: electric-bike

I have a 1999 Giant Lafree Sport ebike which  uses a 24 volt lead acid battery. Does anyone know how to bypass the battery management system/gauge? (Or have a battery box/charger for this bike?)

Answer (score 2):

Those first generation ebikes with lead acid batteries didn’t have real battery management systems - just a low voltage cutoff — if that.

Just get a 24 volt lead acid battery charger.  They’re sold cheap for mobility scooters (the type that elderly and disabled people ride).